# Mono/ASPvNext Distro?

Tags: mono, asp.net

Is there a preconfigured linux distro for running mono applications on linux? I would like to have a "clean working" environment to start from, so I can test my stuff works, before I order a linux box and start to migrate my application. I am interested in running ASP.net vNext on linux too, though this is not a 100% requirement of any pre configured is.